# Onclick event for overflowmenu icon on action bar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

Can I get an onClick or onTouch event for the overflow menu icon on the action bar?
Suppose right navigation drawer is open, when i click on the overflow menu icon, I want to close the navigation drawer, so that they do not overlap.

Any ideas?

Comment: override this method `onOptionsItemSelected` in your activity.

Comment: @Ketan: onOptionsItemSelected gets called only if any menu item is clicked, the overflow icon is not a menu item.